# Using sql_attr_multi in Sphinx Search

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I have some pretty large tables (~30M rows) that have the following similar structure:
- item_id - uint
- item_text - varchar(255)
- user_id - uint

There are no keys, and you can find records with same item_id and item_text but different user_id:

```
item_id, item_text, user_id   
3, text1, 5  
3, text1, 7
4, text2, 5
```

I'm trying to move from MySQL to Sphinx for doing text searches, so how can I translate something like:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=123 AND item_text LIKE '%search_string%'. ?!

With the current sphinx config setup the indexer is running out of disk space:

```
source items
{
    ...
    sql_query_pre = SELECT @id := 0
    sql_query     = SELECT @id := @id + 1, item_id, item_text, user_id FROM items
    sql_attr_uint = user_id
    sql_attr_uint = item_id
}

index items_index
{
    source         = items
    path           = ...
    enable_star    = 1
    min_prefix_len = 0
    min_infix_len  = 3
    min_word_len   = 3
}
```

Is there a way to use sql_attr_multi to store the user_id values found for each item_id ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do,

```
source items {
    ...
    sql_query     = SELECT item_id, item_text, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS user_id \
                     FROM items GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY NULL
    sql_attr_multi = uint user_id from field;
}
```

---

Also asking yourself, if you really min_infix_len? That vastly inflates the disk size (far more than duplicate rows will). Or maybe try dict=keywords

Comment: Already tried the GROUP_CONCAT and it worked :) I'll look into min_ifix_len a little bit more, since it seems like it's using a lot of disk space. Thank you!